# "Self" keyword used for delegate is empty

Tags: ios

I am trying to incorporate OAuthConsumer to interacte with APIs. I'm running into a delegate issue when the "self" keyword is empty.

When the code below is placed inside of the only viewController everything works. When the code is put inside of a class called wpOAuth, that is then called from the viewController the "self" keyword is empty which causes this error:
**requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7172ac0**

```
-(void)getKey:(UIViewController *) uiViewController{
    NSLog(@"\n\nGet Key!!!!!");
    OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"fsdfsdsdfsdfsdf"
                                                    secret:@"sdfdsfsdfsdf"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-public.netflix.com/oauth/request_token"];

    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                                      token:nil   // we don't have a Token yet
                                                                      realm:nil   // our service provider doesn't specify a realm
                                                          signatureProvider:nil]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];
}

- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {
    if (ticket.didSucceed) {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //requestToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
        NSLog(@"%@",[[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody]);
        NSLog(@"\nticket is????????????????????????????= %@ ",ticket.body);
    }
}
```

Any insight into why the self keyword is empty would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
4D

Comment: The `self` keyword is not empty, it's filled with 4 characters. Please use correct terminology as not doing so makes your question meaningless.

Comment: Can you please show the start of the error message, just before "**requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:]: unrecognized selector**".

Comment: Here is the full error:2012-11-27 11:26:43.204 SImpleNetflixAPISearch[56975:c07] -[NSISUnrestrictedVariable requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7172ac0

Comment: @H2CO3, seriously, there's no need for that level of pedanticism. This could be due to a lack of understanding of the problem, and as such we're here to help either way.

Comment: @WDUK What level of pedanticism? I didn't understand the question!

Comment: @H2CO3 "The `self` keyword is not empty, it's filled with 4 characters" is quite a rude way to help. Anyway, enough of our bickering, let's help! :)

Comment: Since the message is being sent to a private object type, the odds are that your delegate has been released before the request finishes (and the memory reused for a `NSISUnrestrictedVariable` -- whatever that is).  If you turn on zombies, you may get a better idea of just where that's happening.

Comment: @WDUK I tried my best - I initially guessed OP meant it was `nil` but it's not the case, since messaging `nil` is not an error. Don't you believe that ***I honestly haven't at all understood the question because of the lack of proper terminology?***

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with delegates handled this way but I think you need to add `- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data;` to your header to define the method. It looks like `OADataFetcher` isn't using a protocol so when it trys to call the method on your object it's not visible since you don't have it defined.

Comment: Here is an debug image of the above code that shows the "self" property is a class that is error / unknown. I can't embed an image so here is a link freeimagehosting.net/p4qyb I added the method in the header file to no effect. To note in, the OAuthConsumer code is not using ARC while the rest of my code is.